# Unmarshal error in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

This is the generated code for "PersonType" class.

```
package demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PersonType", propOrder = {
"name",
"address"
})
public class PersonType {

@XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
protected String name;
@XmlElement(name = "Address", required = true)
protected List<AddressType> address;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String value) {
    this.name = value;
}


public List<AddressType> getAddress() {
    if (address == null) {
        address = new ArrayList<AddressType>();
    }
    return this.address;
}

}
```

This is the generated code for "AddressType" class.

```
    package demo;

 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 @XmlType(name = "AddressType", propOrder = {
"number",
"street"
 })
public class AddressType {

@XmlElement(name = "Number")
@XmlSchemaType(name = "unsignedInt")
protected long number;
@XmlElement(name = "Street", required = true)
protected String street;


public long getNumber() {
    return number;
}


public void setNumber(long value) {
    this.number = value;
}


public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String value) {
    this.street = value;
}

}
```

This is the xml file I want to unmarshal

```
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\JAXB Demo\demo.xsd">
  <Name>Sharon Krisher</Name>
  <Address>
    <Street>Iben Gevirol</Street>
    <Number>57</Number>
  </Address>
<Address>
  <Street>Moshe Sharet</Street>
   <Number>89</Number>
  </Address>
</Person>
```

Code foe unarchall

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PersonType.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller =context.createUnmarshaller();
    //unmarshaller.setValidating(true);
    PersonType person =(PersonType) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("C:\\Users\\sithi\\workspace\\TestJAXB\\src\\data.xml") );
```

This code gives an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"PersonType"). Expected elements are (none)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to associate a class with a root element.  The first is `@XmlRootElement` on the class, the second is an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation on a class annotated with `@XmlRegistry` (when the model is generated from an XML a Schema this class is called `ObjectFactory`.

**Creating the `JAXBContext`**

When you generate a model from XML Schema you should create the `JAXBContext` on the package name:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("demo");
```

Or generated `ObjectFactory` class:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(demo.ObjectFactory.class);
```

This will make sure the `ObjectFactory` class is processed.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

**No `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlElementDecl`?**

If there isn't an `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlElementDecl` associating a class with the root element of your document then you will need to use one of the unmarshal methods that take a class parameter.

```
PersonType pt = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, PersonType.class).getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your PersonType class doesn't have `@XmlRootElement`. I think you'd want to do the "Unmarshalling into a known type" example in this page, which doesn't require @XmlRootElement on PersonType .

Comment: Please can u explain more. I can't undestand what is @XmlRootElement.

Comment: It defines root element of your xml in your case person is root element Refer the below example http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/jaxb-tutorial-getting-started.html